# How to add a cart icon with add to cart button in catalog category page in magento 2?

Tags: css, magento, frontend, magento2, issue-tracking

Can anybody tell me that how can i add a cart icon with add to cart button in catalog category page in magento2 ?

I tried to this by adding CSS but cant get successful. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the answer for both Catalog Category and Product Page

***1. Catalog Category***

Step 1:- Create a **catalog_category_view.xml** file in vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Sunarc_Custom::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 2:- Create your custom **list.phtml** file in vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product folder.Copy the code from the core file and add your icon to it.

```
 <button type="submit" title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="action tocart primary" disabled> <span>
     <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i> &nbsp;<?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
 </button>
```

Result : [image]

***2. Catalog Product View***

Step 1:-  Create a **catalog_product_view.xml** file in vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Sunarc_Custom::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Sunarc_Custom::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 2:- Create your custom **addtocart.phtml** file in vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view folder.Copy the code from the core file and add your icon to it.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) :?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()) :?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       min="0"
                       value="<?= $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitle) ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button" disabled>
                <span><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i> &nbsp;<?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitle) ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Result:-
[image]